# Syntax error on ec2 bash script

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2

It´s been a long time since I have to touch on bash and now I have aproblem on my script and I dont have any idea why

```
  #!/bin/bash

  echo “Getting amazon instance Id”

  instanceId =  ´/usr/bin/ec2metadata --instance-id´

  echo “Adding tags for instance Id”  $instanceId

  /usr/bin/ec2-create-tags -O key -W password $instanceId --region eu-west-1 --tag 'Name=GV Jenkins Slave' --tag 'Billing-Group=VERTICALX'
```

The problem is about instanceId, when I execute the script it told me "ec2CreateTags.sh: 7: ec2CreateTags.sh: instanceId: not found
" 
Any idea what is wrong.
BTW I try putting the ´ in the instanceId and without with the same result

Regards.

Comment: remove the space between the variable name `instanceId` and `=`, you're not actually assigning to it yet.

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: got it!, very nice the shellcheck thank you so much

Comment: using forwardticks inline `instanceId =  ´/usr/bin/ec2metadata --instance-id´` are possible to use for running a command?. should be bakticks or `$(...)`

Comment: you´re right I already put it thanks!!

Comment: Rather than using the old command-line tools (eg ec2-create-tags), I'd recommend using the newer AWS Command-Line Interface: http://aws.amazon.com/cli/